# How to increment numbers in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print odd numbers from 1 - 99, using the script below.

```
start=1
while [[ $start -le 100 ]]
do 
    echo $start
    start=start+2

done
```

but instead of getting numbers my output looks like

```
1
1+2
1+2+2
1+2+2+2
1+2+2+2+2
1+2+2+2+2+2
1+2+2+2+2+2+2
1+2+2+2+2+2+2+2
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: for addition you should use `start=$((start+2))`

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about the difference?

Comment: [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically detects the problem and has a wiki page with [additional information](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2100)

Comment: [Here is some more details](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) the link is from [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: I'm surprised you see that output with that code: I see `bash: [[: start+2: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "start+2")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [Aritmetic Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html):

> Arithmetic expansion provides a powerful tool for performing (integer) arithmetic operations in scripts.

Example:

```
start=$((start + 2))
```

The cleanest code I can do to print odd numbers is:

```
start=1
while [[ $start -le 100 ]]
do
    echo $((start += 2))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello try something like this:

```
for (( NUM=1; NUM<=100; NUM=NUM+2 )); do
    echo $NUM
done
```

Comment: That prints even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Jest wrap the `start+2` like below

```
start=$((start+2))
```

[Here is some more details](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

The link is from [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: Could you tell me more about the difference,

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your problem is that you're not increasing the number properly, you have to use something like

```
start=$((start + 2))
```

or

```
((start += 2))
```

However, you can avoid the whole loop:

```
printf '%d\n' {1..100..2}
```